# Changing HTML content using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I need to change this HTML:

```
<div class="wp-pagenavi">
    <ul>
        <li class="active">
            <span>1</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a rel="start" data-ci-pagination-page="10" href="http://devserver/index.php/blog/page/10">2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="next">
            <a rel="next" data-ci-pagination-page="10" href="http://devserver/index.php/blog/page/10">→</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

To this one:

```
<span class="current">1</span>
<a href="#" class="page">2</a>
<a href="#" class="page">3</a>
<a href="#" class="page">4</a>
<a href="#" class="page">5</a>
```

Using jQuery. I think to use the method [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) but don't know how to maitain values. Samples for doc aren't enough to get this working, any advice?

**EDIT Clarify post**

- As many can see I trying to change a code generated in CodeIgniter but as part of a CMS called PyroCMS so change the way in how pagination links are generated could be a problem later with Pyro Team updates or new releases so this isn't an option
- In the other part changing static wont work because links are generated dinamically so today as the example show are 1,2,3,4 but maybe tomorrow can be 1,2,3 or 1,2,3,4,5,6 or wathever

**EDIT 2**: added a container for the UL so I can use `$('.wp-pagenavi')` instead of just `ul`

**EDIT 3 Solution**: based on @lewsid (you not give me the answer but help to find a solution by myself so I'll accept your answer) solution and help I build my own that just works as I want, here is the code:

```
var newContent = "";
$('.wp-pagenavi ul > li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('class') == "active") {
        newContent += "<span class='current'>" + $(this).find("span").html() + "</span>&nbsp;";
    } else {
        newContent += "<a class='page' href='" + $(this).find("a").attr("href") + "'>" + $(this).find("a").html() + "</a>&nbsp;";
    }
});

$('.wp-pagenavi ul').replaceWith(newContent);
```

Comment: Why use code igniter to mess up the HTML you want to have in the first place and then use jquery to put it back?

Comment: @mplungjan I'm not using CodeIgniter, I'm using PyroCMS (a CMS based on it) changing the way how pagination are generated means change CORE and this will be a problem later with updates from Pyro Team, for that reason I think the best is to change using jQuery or Javascript, or I'm not right?

Comment: Can you show the full structure of changes you want to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are far more elegant ways to do this, but here's a quick-and-dirty solution you might try. Assuming the output is inside a div with a class of 'output':

```
//Loop over list items
$('.wp-pagenavi ul').each(function(i, obj) {
    var position = i + 1;
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $('.output').append('<span class="current">'+position+'</span>');
    }
    else {
        $('.output').append('<a href="#" class="page">'+position+'</a>');
    }
});

//Don't need this anymore
$('.wp-pagenavi ul').remove();
```

Comment: this has more sense but I'm getting this error: `TypeError: obj.hasClass is not a function: if (obj.hasClass('active')) {` also I edited the main post and add a `.wp-pagenavi` div so you can use `$('.wp-pagenavi ul')` instead of just `$('ul')`

Comment: Updated, give this a shot!

Answer (score -1):

must it be with jquery ?? what about simple javascript with innerHTML like this:

```
<ul id="myUl">
    <li class="active">
        Original Content
    </li>
</ul>
<script language="Javascript">
    document.getElementById('myUl').innerHTML = '<span>Content replaced blah blah      </span>';
</script>
```

(For simplicity I added the id attribute, but you get the idea)

Comment: could u please share the reason for the downvoting ?